# My question is about creating a multiplication table with php

Tags: php

I was trying to create a multiplication table with "php" and "html" where the user can insert the number of rows and columns by using an html form.

The table have to have numbered columns and rows which show the two factors of every number.
This picture explains more: the numbers that show the column and row numbers are bold.

[image: multiplication table example]

This is the combination code of html and php code I have used which did not work.

```
<form method=get>
number of rows: <input type=text name=m><br>
number of columns: <input type=text name=n>
<input type=submit value="Sii daa"> 
<style>
table,td {
  border: 5px solid salmon;
}
</style>
</form>

<?php
echo '<table>';
print '<tr>';
echo '<td></td> \n';
for($row=1;$row<=$_GET[m];$row++){
    echo "<td>$col</td> \n";
}
echo "</tr>";

for ($col=1;$col<=$_GET[n];$col++){
    echo "</tr> \n";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the intval of the GET parameters, then you have m rows, each having n columns:

```
<form method=get>
    number of rows: <input type=text name=m><br>
    number of columns: <input type=text name=n>
    <input type=submit value="Sii daa">
    <style>
        table, td {
            border: 5px solid salmon;
        }
    </style>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["m"]) && isset($_GET["n"])) {
    $m = intval($_GET["m"]);
    $n = intval($_GET["n"]);
    echo '<table>';
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $m; $row++) {
        print '<tr>';
        for ($col = 1; $col <= $n; $col++) {
            echo "<td>$col</td> \n";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

But anyway, you better not ask people to solve your problem, instead, you should ask a particular and clear question regarding your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I was only trying to learn how to do such thing but that you answered my question, I know now how to do such thing.